# Formula in page header based on number of row details in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I'm a newbie in Crystal Reports and still in the process of learning. Got stuck with this problem. What I want is, the maximum rows that my details section can handle is 13 rows in my first page when it become 14 then it turns to the 2nd page as well as my page header and totals.

But what if it its only 13th rows I still have page header in my 2nd page. Is there a formula wherein page header in my 2nd page will be print only if this is the 14th row of my details section? (I still have Page footer and Report Footer after details section).

Comment: if you are having only 13 record then why you want to go for next pag?

Comment: Sorry, for the 1st page 13 rows is the maximum so for 2nd page I still have page footer and report footer. but the page header still displays.